# Generate dynamic pie chart on click event on a stacked line chart IN DOJO

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I am using Dojo to generate alternate chart on click event of previous chart.

Firstly, i am drawing stacked line chart(say for Customers) and on clicking one of the line i need to draw another pie chart for further details of that Customer(say revenue by that customer). All that is happening for a single line chart.

Here Problem is to find id for that particular line, now i am getting array of ids for all plotted lines. 
Following graph is drawn for three Customers.

[image]
And Following I am presenting my code :

```
 var colorArray =["#2cabe2","#57E964","#736AFF","#B93B8F","#151B8D","#EE9A4D",...];
 for(var i =0 ; i<length ; i++)
        {
         chart.addSeries(response.legend + " "+ i,response.data[i],{color: colorArray[i]});
        } 

 chart.connectToPlot("default", function(evt) {
        var shape = evt.shape, type = evt.type;
        if (type == "onclick") {
          url="/ritl/chart/getProcessPieData.htm?customerId="+dijit.byId('customerId').get('value');   // url to the next (pie) chart in the same jsp.  
          processPie(url);         // calling function for pie Chart

        }
    });
```

---

Data Response is in the form of JSONArray. JSON pattern is as:

```
{"data":[[{"text":"January","value":1,"customerID":"RITL00013","y":0},{"text":"February","value":2,"customerID":"RITL00013","y":0},{"text":"March","value":3,"customerID":"RITL00013","y":0},{"text":"April","value":4,"customerID":"RITL00013","y":0},{"text":"May","value":5,"customerID":"RITL00013","y":0},{"text":"June","value":6,"customerID":"RITL00013","y":0},{"text":"July","value":7,"customerID":"RITL00013","y":0},{"text":"August","value":8,"customerID":"RITL00013","y":0},{"text":"September","value":9,"customerID":"RITL00013","y":0},{"text":"October","value":10,"customerID":"RITL00013","y":119951.2},{"text":"November","value":11,"customerID":"RITL00013","y":430827.04},{"text":"December","value":12,"customerID":"RITL00013","y":0}],[{"text":"January","value":1,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":0},{"text":"February","value":2,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":0},{"text":"March","value":3,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":0},{"text":"April","value":4,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":0},{"text":"May","value":5,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":0},{"text":"June","value":6,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":0},{"text":"July","value":7,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":0},{"text":"August","value":8,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":0},{"text":"September","value":9,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":0},{"text":"October","value":10,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":41996.52},{"text":"November","value":11,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":566353.8099999999},{"text":"December","value":12,"customerID":"RITL00002","y":0}],[{"text":"January","value":1,"customerID":"RITL00016","y":0},{"text":"February","value":2,"customerID":"RITL00016","y":0},{"text":"March","value":3,"customerID":"RITL00016","y":0},{"text":"April","value":4,"customerID":"RITL00016","y":0},{"text":"May","value":5,"customerID":"RITL00016","y":0},{"text":"June","value":6,"customerID":"RITL00016","y":0},{"text":"July","value":7,"customerID":"RITL00016","y":0},{"text":"August","value":8,"customerID":"RITL00016","y":0},{"text":"September","value":9,"customerID":"RITL00016","y":0},{"text":"October","value":10,"customerID":"RITL00016","y":132784.45},{"text":"November","value":11,"customerID":"RITL00016","y":571506.6},{"text":"December","value":12,"customerID":"RITL00016","y":0}]],"Success":true,"dataLength":3}
```

How to find out the individual id for the line in the above Chart. Suggest me to get out of this situation. Thanks in advance for active suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like the following in your connectPlot callback:

```
event.run.data[event.index].customerID
```

Comment: Thanks Man, its working.. Here [event.index] returning the index of x axis but data[event.index] is undefined without event.run ??

Comment: i got an issue again in Stacked line chart. for that you can go to the link...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21250642/dojo-addseries-method-in-a-loop-ploting-a-graph-with-commulative-sum
Thanks in advance..